# Add a class to a DIV when a checkbox is selected within DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to add a class to a div if the checkbox within it is selected.

For example, the following are a group of checkboxes. If checkbox with label **Physician Name1** is selected, I would like to add class to the div that contains the class **phys1**. If user selects **Physician Name2**, remove the border from previous selection and add class to the div that contains **phys2**.

```
<div class="row step-2-paddingBot">
    <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys1">
        <div class="phys-name">
            <input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys2">
        <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name2</label></span><br />
        <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys3">
        <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name3</label></span><br />
        <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW all those `<br />` are not a great way to do formatting; suggest you wrap elements in something like a `<div>` and add classes to those to enhance your formatting capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code checks if the checkbox is checked on click then goes up to the closest div adding him a class. Changed one of the div's to span so it will work as expected.

```js
$("[type=checkbox]").click(function(ev) {
  $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("active", this.checked);

})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row step-2-paddingBot">
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys1">
    <span class="phys-name">
      <input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name1</label>
    </span>
    <div class="adj-address">
      Address: Address<br /> Line 1, Address<br /> Address Line 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys2">
    <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name2</label></span><br />
    <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys3">
    <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name3</label></span><br />
    <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the closest ancestor by a class and then toggle a class based on the checkbox value (checked or not) pretty easily.  I added some CSS and a background color just to illustrate.

Note I used both a click and a change so it honors the change no matter how the checked property gets altered.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on(change', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
  let isChecked = this.checked;
  $(this).closest('.phys-group').toggleClass("cheese", isChecked);
});
```

```css
.phys-group{
border: solid 1px #DDFFDD;
}
.phys-group.cheese {
  background-color: #FFEEEE;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row step-2-paddingBot">
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys1 phys-group">
    <div class="phys-name">
      <input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="adj-address">
      Address: Address<br /> Line 1, Address<br /> Address Line 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys2 phys-group">
    <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name2</label></span><br />
    <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-text phys3 phys-group">
    <span class="phys-name"><input type="checkbox"> <label class="adjust-label">Physician Name3</label></span><br />
    <span class="adj-address">
            Address: Address<br />
            Line 1, Address<br />
            Address Line 2
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: onclick would fire even when using a keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but this also allows the value to be changed via code and detects that.

Comment: And no way they both gonna fire (when clicked)?

Comment: They do both fire on a click - so perhaps better to use the "change" only otherwise you have to detect which; here is a code change example using that for the first checkbox `$('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).prop('checked', true).trigger("change");`

Comment: I updated to the :"change" and also added an example wo show the event type that fired. IF you wanted you could also add an additional event like "codechanged" and trigger that and do custom based on that etc